# Python function to add different words to dataframe columns depending on how many words certain columns contain

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an example dataframe with various columns including A, B and C shown here.

Using Pandas in Python, I'm looking to add some text to each cell in these A, B and C columns as follows:

- If cell contains 1 word, concatenate cell value and the specific word "Single"
- If cell contains 2 words, concatenate cell value and the specific word "Double"
- Otherwise show specific word "check"

Here is a quick example in Excel to show you the intention. The helper columns in the middle aren't needed as such explicitly, just to make the example clearer.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this (assuming the empty cells are `''`, not `NaN` --if they are `NaN`, do a `.fillna('')` first):

```py
dct = {0: 'Empty', 1: 'Single', 2: 'Double'}
z = df.applymap(lambda s: len(s.split()))
newdf = df + ' ' + z.replace(dct).where(z.isin(set(dct)), 'other')

>>> newdf
                      A                   B                 C
0          Apple Single        B3sin Single    Pd Turn Double
1  Giraffe p7nda Double  Drum corner Double        Cut Single
2         Andrex Single      Ed wurn Double  Warn Gert Double
3        A flush Double               Empty      H 8uw Double
4       Phone Hu Double         a b c other             Empty
```

BTW, **reproducible setup**:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': ['Apple', 'Giraffe p7nda', 'Andrex', 'A flush', 'Phone Hu'],
     'B': ['B3sin', 'Drum corner', 'Ed wurn', '', 'a b c'],
     'C': ['Pd Turn', 'Cut', 'Warn Gert', 'H 8uw', ''],
    })
```

**Edit**

Alternative, as a single expression that is impervious to `NaN` as missing values:

```py
newdf = df.applymap(
    lambda s: s + ' ' + {1: 'Single', 2: 'Double'}.get(len(s.split()), 'check') \
        if s and s == s else s)

>>> newdf
                      A                   B                 C
0          Apple Single        B3sin Single    Pd Turn Double
1  Giraffe p7nda Double  Drum corner Double        Cut Single
2         Andrex Single      Ed wurn Double  Warn Gert Double
3        A flush Double                          H 8uw Double
4       Phone Hu Double         a b c check
```

As an aside, speed:

```py
%timeit df.applymap(lambda s: s + ' ' + {1: 'Single', 2: 'Double'}.get(len(s.split()), 'check') if s and s == s else s)
# 450 µs ± 421 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Just calculating `z` in the original answer takes about that long:

```py
%timeit df.applymap(lambda s: len(s.split()))
# 432 µs ± 463 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

And trying to use `.str` in an attempt to get a vectorized expression won't speed things up (`.str` methods are not vectorized):

```py
%timeit df.transform(lambda s: s.str.split().str.len())
# 1.14 ms ± 6.51 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with [`len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html), [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) :

```
suffix = (df.stack().str.split().str.len()
          .map({1: " Single", 2: " Double"}).unstack())
​
out = df.add(suffix)
​
```

Output :

```
print(out)
                      A                   B                 C
0          Apple Single        B4sin Single    Pd Turn Double
1  Giraffe p8nda Double  Drum corner Double        Cut Single
2         Andrex Single      Ed wurn Double  Warn Gert Double
3        A flush Double                 NaN      H 8uw Double
4       Phone Hu Double                 NaN               NaN
```